# Set array value using multiple dynamic keys

Tags: javascript

I am currently creating a dynamic multidimensional array in Javascript.
First of all I want to create a dynamic checklist array.

First I create my first checklist then I want to make a sub checklist for my main checklist. Then I want to create a sub checklist for that particular sub checklist also and so on.

[image]

see my below script

```
function get_item_checklist(){ //should convert the sample image to object
  var arr = [];
  $("#checklist-body").find("div.card").each(function(){
    var list_name = $(this).find("list_name").val();
    var $body = $(this).find("div.card-body div.list_item");
    if($body.length){
      var list_arr = [];
      var list_rec = [];
      $(body).each(function(){
        var desc = $(this).find("input.desc").val();
        var list_no = parseInt($(this).find("input.req-no").val()) - 1;
        var sub_no = $(this).find("input.sub-no").val();
        list_rec.push({"list_no":list_no,"sub_no":sub_no});
        if(list_no && !sub_no){
          if(!list_arr[list_no]){
            list_arr[list_no] = [];
          }
          list_arr[list_no].push({"desc":desc}); // will simply just push since there is no sub#
        }else if(list_no && sub_no){
          sub_no = parseInt(sub_no) - 1;
          var parent_nos = look_parent_list_no(list_rec,sub_no);
          if(parent_nos){ 
            if(parent_nos.length == 1){ //for only one parent checklist
              if(!list_arr[parent_nos[0]][sub.no]){ //if not set
                list_arr[parent_nos[0]][sub.no] = [];
              }
              list_arr[parent_nos[0]][sub_no].push({"desc":desc});
            }else{
              // if parent nos are multiple
              // END OF MY SCRIPT HERE <<<<<<--------
            }
          }
        }
      });
      arr.push({"name":list_name,"description":list_arr});
    }else{
      arr.push({"name":list_name});
    }
  });
};
function look_parent_list_no(arr,no,arr1){ // this will get all the list # of parents in order to know where to put exactly the sub checklist
  if(typeof arr1 != "object"){
    arr1 = [];
  }
  for(key in arr){
    console.log(arr[key],no);
    if(arr[key].list_no == no && !arr[key].sub_no){
      arr1.push(arr[key].list_no);
      return arr1;
    }else if(arr[key].list_no == no && arr[key].sub_no){
      arr1.push(arr[key].list_no);
      return look_parent_list_no(arr,arr[key].sub_no,arr1);
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

I am now having a problem if a sub checklist have a parent of parent, you can see it in the list # 5. List 5 should be inside of list #4 where in list #4 is inside of list #2.

below `object` is my expected output to my `get_item_checklist()`

```
[
  {
    name: "My Parent list 1",
    description : 
    [
      {
        desc: "sublist 1"
      },
      {
        desc: "sublist 2",
        items: 
        [
          {
            desc: "sublist 1 of 2"
          },
          {
            desc: "sublist 2 of 2",
            items: [
              {
                desc: "sublist 1 of 2 of 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This looks like a case which may fall under the `Composite Design Pattern`, you may want to look at this: (https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/composite-design-pattern)

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the amount of code you're showing here? It's a little difficult to focus on the specific problem here

Comment: just focus on my last script with example. if I have a dynamic keys how can I set the array using those keys

Comment: @OliverRadini Why did you delete your answer? and down voted my question? Just because i am in favor of other answer? I just chose which is the best answer. you can justify your answer if you think it should be chosen over the other

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez because the answer I gave didn't properly answer the question and I don't have time to correct it. I downvoted your question because it doesn't clearly state what is required. You could improve the question by providing a clear example of the data you have, and what you need to do with it, without any extra details. That'll make it easier for people to give good answers

Comment: @OliverRadini I tried putting my sample code because i need to do it first on my own. It is not allowed here to post a question without trying by my own. You can look at my expected output. I udpate my question with expected output.

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez Sure, but the idea is to post _only_ the parts which are relevant to the question. It seems that other people who have attempted to answer this question are having similar issues so it makes sense for you to try and be more precise in your question, if you'd like a good answer

Comment: @OliverRadini I updated my question with all the knowledge i know to clarify this. I added some comments in my scripts in order to know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is used to insert the code exactly in the given dynamic position,

```js
let input = [ 
{ desc:"test1" , list_no : 0 ,sub_no:null }, 
{ desc:"test2" , list_no : 1 ,sub_no:null }, 
{ desc:"test3" , list_no : 2 ,sub_no:null }, 
{ desc:"test1 of 1" , list_no : 3 ,sub_no:0 }, 
{ desc:"test2 of 1" , list_no : 4 ,sub_no:0 }, 
{ desc:"test1 of 2" , list_no : 5 ,sub_no:1 }, 
{ desc:"test1 of 3" , list_no : 6 ,sub_no:2 }, 
{ desc:"test1 of test1 of test 3" , list_no : 7 ,sub_no:6 } 
]; 

let op = []; 
let trackMap = {}; 
input.forEach((obj) => { 
let node = "list_no"; 
let sub_node = "sub_no"; 
let description = "desc"; 
if (obj[sub_node] === null) { 
let objFormed = {desc : obj[description]}; 
trackMap[obj[node]] = objFormed; 
op.push(objFormed); 
} 
else { 
let objFormed = {desc : obj[description]}; 
let parent = trackMap[obj[sub_node]]; 
if (parent) { 
parent.items || (parent.items = []); 
parent.items.push(objFormed) 
} 
trackMap[obj[node]] = objFormed; 
} 
});
```

Comment: Hello, you code seems can run only once. if tried to run again it will get an error

Comment: Hi, Can you post what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: im getting undefined property.

Comment: Whenever the program runs based on the given dynamic keys it will traverse through the length of that array and each position is taken and multidimensional array is formed. The positions which are not given in the dynamic keys array will remain as holes. For me every time it gives me the result and not throwing error.

Comment: I tried recoding already your answer and i got it working.Now i have a big problem because of this multidimension array for my dynamic checklist. I updated my answer, you can see to the last my expected output.

Comment: Sorry Actually I didn't get your question clearly. I saw your expected output. But Can you please elaborate what's your input, expected output and actual output. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194526/discussion-between-john-christian-de-chavez-and-prince-devadoss).